# Why do need to import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts when I've already imported in a separate module where it is used

Tags: angular

I have 2 modules (`AppModule` and `BookModule`), BookModule's component injected a service which uses `HttpClient` so I imported `HttpClientModule` in it. But application still needs to import `HttpClientModule` in AppModule. 
As per my understanding, we need import module where it is needed instead in RootModule.

here is the CodeSanbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-gthir)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901209/why-to-import-httpclientmodule-in-app-module-ts/53901219


duplicate question

Comment: you has in your service:`@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})`, you should use `@Injectable({providedIn: BookModule})` or not use providedIn and include in the providers module

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks for the clarification. I have provided service in 'root' that's why appModule needs to import HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @Eliseo comment, i've clear my doubt about provider.

if the service provided in root scope than its dependency need to be imported in appmodule.

Answer (score 1):

If you import any module like `HttpClientModule` in `AppModule` then components, services, etc, of the imported module will be accessible from every component of your application.

BTW, may be you forgot to import `BookModule` in `AppModule` and for this reason you still need to import `HttpClientModule` in `AppModule` though you already imported `HttpClientModule` in `BookModule`. However, if `BookModule` is imported inside `AppModule` you don't have to import `HttpClientModule` in `AppModule`.

Comment: i've provided service in 'root' scope that's why it was breaking.  When I have provide service in BookModule and remove provided from service then error resolve

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, you haven't import your `Book Module` within `App Module`, Please modify your `app.module.ts` like below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { BookModule } from './book/book.module'; // Import Book Module

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, PageNotFoundComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    BookModule // Add your Module inside the imports array
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now it will work fine without error

I also have attached the screenshot
[image]

Comment: i've used it as a lazy loaded way in app-routing.module.ts. check
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-gthir?file=/src/app/app-routing.module.ts